# element-api plugin / get entry total in section in Craft 3

Tags: plugin-elementapi

What is the best way to get only the total entry number from a section with the least overhead, in the element-api.php?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 2):

Ok i think i stumbled on the answer -

```
$signees = Entry::find()->sectionId(4)->count();
```